# Evaluating $\frac{1}{2\pi} \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}} \, dA$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate the double integral

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}} \, dA.
$$

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen error functions?

Comment: Try polar coordinates.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPyuSmIS8Kk) should be pretty much what you need.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** use polar coordinates:$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\Bbb{R}^2} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}} \, dA 
= \lim_{R\to\infty}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{x^2 +y^2 \le R^2} 
e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}  \, dA 
\\
= \lim_{R\to\infty}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0\le r \le R} 
e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}  2\pi r dr
= \lim_{R\to\infty} \left[-e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}
\right]_0^R
\lim_{R\to\infty} 1-e^{-\frac{R^2}{2}} = 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}} \, dA = \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \, dx \right) \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}} \, dy \right) = \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \, dx \right)^2
$$

This can easily be integrated using polar coordinates (or by recognizing that it is a normal distribution, and so the integral is $\sqrt{2\pi}$).